# Is the image of the projection of a smooth curve onto a subset of its coordinates a manifold if the projection is an injective immersion?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

My question is, I hope, simple. I have a smooth, properly embedded one dimensional submanifold $M \subset R^n, \; n > 2$ (i.e. a smooth curve, which is actually the level set of a smooth function $\phi : R^n \rightarrow R^{n-1}$). I know from separate considerations that the projection $\pi$ of $M$ onto its first two coordinates is a smooth  injective immersion. Can I conclude that then $\pi (M)$ is an embedded submanifold of $R^2$? My sense is no, as I have tried without success (following results in Lee's ISM) to prove that $\pi$ is either a closed or open or proper map onto $\pi(M)$ (with the relative topology, of course), so that $\pi$ will actually be an embedding.

I would appreciate any pointers or comments.

**Edit** After reading the helpful comments I'm thinking the problem may be connected to a sign change of the tangent vector along the curve or perhaps that $dy / dx$ goes undefined. I will explore whether an assumption that the coordinates of the tangent vector never change sign would make a difference. If I come up with anything or have any questions in connection with that I'll post another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Suppose $M$ is the image of the embedding:
$$f(t) =(\cos t,\cos t\sin t, t)$$
defined on $(-3\pi/2, \pi/2)$. This is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbf{R}^3$, but its projection onto the first two coordinates $\pi(M) = \{(\cos t,\cos t \sin t) : -3\pi/2 < t < \pi/2\}$ is a lemniscate in $\mathbf{R}^2$, but with the smooth structure of $\mathbf{R}$. In particular, it is not an embedded submanifold of $\mathbf{R}^2$.

While I am not sure if this is the specific example he uses, I owe this idea to Tu's book on smooth manifolds.

Comment: @William Thank you for responding. As an exercise, I will convince myself that the projection is an injective immersion (a quick check seems to confirm that for me). Is there a quick way you can offer as to how to verify $M$ is proper?

Comment: @HerbF1978 That's perhaps easier if you replace the $t$ in the $z$-coordinate with a tangens-like function that goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ on $(-3\pi/2,\pi/2)$

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Ahh, OK, thanks, I'll look at that. That annoying lemniscate seems to rear its ugly head every time I need an embedded manifold. :)